# trying to vertically center some spans

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<span style="display: inline-block; font-size: 38px; float: left; cursor: pointer; color: #ccc">❮</span>
<span style="margin-top: 12px; background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block"></span>
<span style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block"></span>
<span style="display: inline-block; font-size: 38px; float: right; cursor: pointer; color: #ccc">❯</span>
</div>
```

Here it is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwvxaofc/

The first and last span are being floated left and right whereas the middle three spans are centered horizontally. I want them to also be centered vertically and it is not immediately obvious to me how to do this.

Setting `margin-top: 12px` doesn't seem to do anything.

If I set `position: absolute` for the outer most div and then wrap the three middle span's around in a `<div>` with `position: relative` and `top: 50%` the floats then become messed up.

Comment: Also you can't use `display:inline-block` AND `float`...pick one, not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox` at the place of `floats`. Use the below code:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
  <span style="font-size: 38px;cursor: pointer; color: #ccc">❮</span>
  <div class="dots">
    <span style="margin-top: 12px; background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block"></span>
    <span style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block"></span>
    <span style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block"></span>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size: 38px;cursor: pointer; color: #ccc">❯</span>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ExNVWYz?editors=1000

**I would suggest you not to use inline styles wherever possible. And use a separate file or use the `style` tag. Like this:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ccc;
}

.dots span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dots span.active {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="arrow">❮</span>
  <div class="dots">
    <span class="active"></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <span class="arrow">❯</span>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/gOLamLx?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

Ditch all the floats and `display:inline-block` and use flexbox

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto;
}

span:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <span style="font-size: 38px; cursor: pointer; color: #ccc">❮</span>
  <span style=" background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer;"></span>
  <span style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer;"></span>
  <span style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 50%; height: 13px; width: 13px; cursor: pointer;"></span>
  <span style=" font-size: 38px; cursor: pointer; color: #ccc">❯</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should move all those styles out to an embedded style tag or external stylesheet and use intuitively-named classes. No one likes to work with that sort of markup mess and you have a huge amount of repetition.

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), the way of the future!

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  font-size: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ccc;
}

.nav-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-dot.active {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="nav prev">❮</div>

  <div class="nav-dots">
    <div class="nav-dot active"></div>
    <div class="nav-dot"></div>
    <div class="nav-dot"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav next">❯</div>
</div>
```